# Custom Matplotlib colourmap - like pgfplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

Is it possible to get the Blue-Yellow-Red colourmap from `pgfplots` , as in this example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/scaling-colormaps-with-pgfplots , in `matplotlib` ?

I have taken a look on how to define custom colourmaps in matplotlib, but it seems very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a custom cmap is the way to go though. It's not that difficult but you must make sure you understand all the values in the `color dict`.

For each color you specify three columns of values. The first column is the position at which point a color occurs, 0 being the first and 1 the last. Since you want three colors, there are three evenly spaced positions defined 0, 0.5 and 1.0.

You want:

0.0: Blue

0.5: Yellow

1.0: Red

The second column defines the color 'up to' the position, the third column the color 'from/after' that position. If you want colors to gradually fade you should keep them the same. Specifying different colors allows the colormap to have sudden 'jumps' after a certain position.

To get blue at position 0.0, set red and green to 0 and blue to 1. To get yellow at position 0.5 set red and green to 1 and blue to zero. And so on...

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
        'green':((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
         'blue':((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}

custom_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('mymap', cdict, 256)

plt.imshow(np.arange(36).reshape(6,6), cmap=custom_cmap, interpolation='none')
```

[image]

Comment: On a side note, it's much easier to construct this by using `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mymap', ['blue', 'yellow', 'red'])`

Answer (score 3):

@RutgerKassies has a great explanation of how linear colormaps work in matplotlib in general. When you need colormaps with uneven transitions or "hard" cutoffs, you need to specify the full `dict` of threshold values.

However, there's a convenience "factory function" for simple colormaps with even transitions between colors: [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) (Actually, you can even make uneven transitions with it, just as long as they're not "hard" transitions.)

For example (to steal Rutger's example), we can do this with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mymap', ['blue', 'yellow', 'red'])

plt.imshow(np.arange(36).reshape(6,6), cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your answer :) I would mark your post as accepted because of the simplicity, but I think the previous post was more detailed.

Comment: @DavidWinchester - No worries! Rutger's post is more detailed and a better explanation! I just wanted to show an example of a simpler method. :)